# Drone and sensor recommendations for analyzing tree coverage

Tags: drone

I have been tasked with implementing a project using Drones. The project tries to analyze the distribution of Cocoa trees in the landscape in respect to other tress. One of the main challenges is the identification of Cocoa trees for drone sensing images but also how to determine Cocoa under the canopy of other trees.

I have no drone or sensor experience to determine the technical feasibility of the project (if its possible).

Does anybody know it is possible and what drone + sensor/s would be most suitable for the task?

Comment: If you don't have experience to determine the technical feasibility of the project, you should tell so to the person who asked you to determine it. The fact that someone on this site would tell you that it's possible/impossible won't magically increase your experience.

Comment: Yeah, you're gonna have to pay someone that specializes in this kind of stuff. Nobody on here is going to do that kind of work for you for free.

Comment: Hi, you should go this site since most experience GIS people  can help you on that ...  https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you have a software in mind ?  There are variety software that require at least 8 GB RAM.